# How to validate jsp page using HTMl5

Tags: java, html, jsp, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have two submit button in one form,if I click on first submit button(i.e cashPaymentDiv save butoon) both submit buttons fields are validating. I want to validate only one div while submitting form.

```
    <form name="customerForm" action="saveTransactionBill.do">

<div id="paymentModeDiv">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label
                                    style="margin: 0; width: 100px; display: block; padding: 5px 0; color: #737373; font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; float: left;">Payment
                                        Mode:</label></td>
                                <td><select onchange="showPaymentDivs();"
                                    name="paymentMode">
                                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                                        <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
<div id="cashPaymentDiv" class="required">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Amount Paid:</label></td>
<td><input name="amountPaid" id="cashPaymentForBillWise" onchange="calculateBalAmount();"
required x-moz-errormessage="Enter Username" pattern="[0-9]{0,20}"
title="Please enter only numrics." ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="cash Save"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="chequePaymentDiv" class="required">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Amount Paid:</label></td>
<td><input name="amountPaid" id="cashPaymentForBillWise" onchange="calculateBalAmount();"
required x-moz-errormessage="Enter Username" pattern="[0-9]{0,20}"
title="Please enter only numrics." ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="cheque Save"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: add the validation code

Comment: y arent u using 2 forms?

Comment: Because I have only one controller for this form. I cant use two forms now.I used drop down 1. For cash 2. For cheque. If I select cash, amount paid will display. after adding amount when i click on save button. Second cheque submit also working.

Comment: Because I have only one controller for this form. I cant use two forms now.I used drop down 1. For cash 2. For cheque. If I select cash, amount paid will display. after adding amount when i click on save button. Second cheque submit validation also working. I don't want validation while submitting first save button.

Comment: ok fine....i wud suggest u use ajax for the first part

Comment: also i cant see your dropdown in the code.

Comment: Please check my code now

Comment: but where is ur validation code?

Comment: For validation I used HTML5 code like patter, required fields

Comment: i would suggest u use jquery for this..dont validate with html but instead do using jquery.first find which submit button is clicked,depending on the `value` attribute,use `if else` if first submit is clicked then u validate the first field and submit the form,similarly for else..